# ¿Cómo corregir este programa sobre arreglos en Java?

Tags: java, netbeans

es primera vez que consulto porque no tengo ni idea de cual es el error y estaba haciendo un programa que trata sobre un arreglos, este es el enunciado:

> Ingresar N números enteros a un vector A, luego ingresar un numero cualquiera, se pide pasar aun nuevo vector B todos los números menores al número que ingreso, en caso no exista ninguno, mostrar un mensaje correspondiente.

**El problema esta en que siempre los 3 primeros dígitos que se ingresen siempre se imprimen**, sin importar si sea mayor o menor. *Por ejemplo el número a comparar es 10 y ingresas 12 en el primer valor que te piden, al final lo imprime.* Agradecería mucho si me hacen notar el error o al menos darme una pista.

Este es el código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n, i, x, j = 0;
        int A[] = new int[40], B[] = new int[40];

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese el número de elementos");
        n = scan.nextInt();

        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Ingrese un número");
            A[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Ingrese el número a comparar");
        x = scan.nextInt();
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if (A[i] < x)
            {
                B[j] = A[i];
                j++;
            }
        }

        if (j == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("No se encontro un número menor o igual a " + x);
        } else
        {
            System.out.println("Los números menores o iguales a " + x + " son:");
            for (i = 1; i <= j; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(A[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que debes de imprimir los valores de `B` no de `A`, `System.out.println(B[i]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes he de mencionar que las posiciones de un array empiezan siempre en 0. En el caso del array A, empiezas introduciendo valores en la posición 1. Trata siempre de empezar por la posición 0.

Por otra parte, el error es que siempre muestras el array A, cuando en realidad deberías de mostrar el array B.